# Does giving arguments with (new or declaring new variable) has difference in ram usage?

Tags: c#, performance, ram

I was programming the other day and I was curious as to whether or not

giving arguments with new

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

or declaring new variable

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Application.Run(form1);
```

has difference in ram usage, speed, ...etc

Do they differ from another?

Comment: You might want to play with [measureIt](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2009/02/06/measureit-update-tool-for-doing-microbenchmarks.aspx) to investigate speed.

Comment: @rene Thanks. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

I defined this method to show the difference:

```
public string Run(string param)
{
    return param + "!";
}
```

I then called it these two ways:

(1)

```
    var text = "Hello";
    Console.WriteLine(Run(text));
```

(2)

```
    Console.WriteLine(Run("Hello"));
```

The first produces this IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Hello"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // text
IL_0007:  ldarg.0     
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     // text
IL_0009:  call        Run
IL_000E:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0013:  nop         
IL_0014:  ret
```

The second produces this IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldstr       "Hello"
IL_0007:  call        Run
IL_000C:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0011:  nop         
IL_0012:  ret
```

The difference is the IL `stloc.0`. The first method allocates storage for the `text` variable prior to the call. The second method doesn't.

The difference is very very minor though.

The optimized code for each are:

(1)

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       "Hello"
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // text
IL_0006:  ldarg.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // text
IL_0008:  call        Run
IL_000D:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0012:  ret
```

(2)

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Hello"
IL_0006:  call        Run
IL_000B:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0010:  ret
```

Still the same change in storage - just less `nop`s.

Comment: Yes, it is debug IL. With optimized code the increase in storage is still there, but you're right, the `nop`s are gone.

Comment: As a sidenote, with the example code in this post an extra parameter is introduced which validates the need for the local variables. In optimized code the `new Form1 etc` of the OP's example, the stloc and ldloc would be optimized away. (provided there are no further references to the variable)

Comment: @Me.Name not in the IL I get (with the 4.0 compiler) ... might be that the JIT-er that optimizes.

Comment: @Me.Name - I've posted both the debug and release (optimized) code and both have the `stloc` and `ldloc`. I agree with rene that I would expect that the JIT-er removes them, if anything.

Comment: Aha, seems to be one of the VS2015 optimizations. Did the same in VS2013 and they remain. The amended side note would be, from VS2015 onwards... :D

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the case of

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

the Form1 object is only in scope of the `Run` call and eligible for garbage collection immediately after.

Whereas with

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Application.Run(form1);
```

the `form1` is still in scope after the `Run` and can't be GC'd until the end of the block.
This can (probably not in this case, but for other objects) have quite an impact of runtime memory usage.

Answer (score -2):

No there is no difference. Application.Run(..) method can hold the reference to the Form instance. So GC does not utilize this. It doesn't matter if you declare `form1` variable or not as the reference to it is lost when the method ends execution.

Comment: Turns out there is a difference.

Comment: @rene Yes. Thought it should be optimized. It's interesting why not.